# Cannot connect to Wired ethernet on ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu

I have Ubuntu 10.04 on my DELL-LAPTOP. I am new to linux.

I am not able to connect with the wired ethernet connection (it connects on Windows XP on the same machine). It was working fine before but cannot connect now.

How do I figure out where the problem is?

Comment: post 'ifconfig -a' from a terminal window

Answer (score 1):

Try opening a terminal window and enter the following:

```
sudo ifup -a
```

...to try and bring up all network interfaces or...

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
```

...to bring up just the first ethernet adapter.

Most of the time the first wired interface under linux is named eth0. This should tell eth0 to start running and, depending upon configuration, use DHCP to get an address. Alternatively, you could enter:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.10 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.1.255
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
```

...to set a static IP address of 192.168.1.10 (replace as necessary for your network). If none of these work, you may be lacking a linux driver for your particular NIC.